# SimpleXml Failed to Generate Object

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am using Soap for web service call and PHP for entire operation. When I send request I get the response as `341025COMPLETE`. But when I select it for Source it prints the XML behind it.

We have passed it to `simplexml_load_string` function but it failed to generate the object for the same.

What will be wrong with `simplexml_load_string`? When that same string is hard coded it works when it passed through function parameter it failed.

XML that i am getting is :

```
<applicantscreening xmlns="https://www.example.com/xml/services/PSI"><response><reportid>00000</reportid><backgroundreport></backgroundreport><status>TEST</status></response></applicantscreening>
```

Comment: Can you add the exact XML you are getting ???

Comment: Sounds like you are viewing the response in a browser which may be misleading you by hiding the XML tags (because it treats them as HTML tags). If you view-source then you will see any XML tags that are present in the data.

Comment: @MrCode: It shows me only string when i view selection source its XML string.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be something wrong in xml .

Can you please provide xml string ?

Look at the simple example :

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
<title>Forty What?</title>
<from>Joe</from>
<to>Jane</to>
<body>
 I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
</body>
</document> 
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
print_r($xml);
```